# need some direction on google sites developement

Tags: asp.net, integration, google-sites

Some companies are use google sites ( sites.google.com )  as their intranet. I want to do some development to develop a webapp on google sites based on a a webapp we already have (with webservices , database servers , asp.net  running already ).  Can I use my asp.net web services via AJAX in the google site ?

What tutorial and documentation do you recommend on integration involving google sites ?

Any starter information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked there was no ability to add javascript or css to the pages on google sites.